axios has no exported module AxiosInstance
class HttpService {
    apiEndPoints = ApiEndPoints;
    appRoutes = AppRoutes;
    baseUrl = '...............http';
    http: AxiosInstance
    constructor() {
        this.http = axios.create({
            baseURL: this.baseUrl,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        });
}

in the code i have updated the typescript and axios to latest
but it still gives the error that  the axios has no exported module AxiosInstance
i tried the following ways but none of them work
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from 'axios';

and use it as
 http: AxiosInstance


also tried it in the following way
import axios from 'axios';

and use it as
http: axios.AxiosInstance 
but still not working
